# How Do I Disable URL Pre-Pending in the FireFox 3 Title Bar When Opeing A New Window With JavaScript?

Tags: firefox, javascript, url

For (understandable) security reasons, Firefox does not allow JavaScript to open a new window without the address/location bar AND without pre-pending the page's URL to the title in the title bar.

For example, when you set:

```
<title>My Site</title>
```

in the header, and open the page using

```
location=no
```

FireFox changes the header to read:

```
http://www.mysite.com - My Site - Mozilla Firefox.
```

I would like it to simply say:

```
My Site
```

Everything I've read suggests this behaviour can't be altered with scripting, and as such, this is not a scripting question.

What I would like to know is, which setting(s) can I change in the *browser* itself to disable URL pre-pending to the title of new windows?

This is for a company Intranet, and I control all of the computers/browsers that connect to the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an add-on that does it-

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10495

I was hoping there might be a configuration option somewhere, and would be interested if anyone knows of one.

Comment: TitlebarTweaks is probably your best bet.